Change margin for widget on Android
I am building an app on Android. My app can create the widget on the home screen.
However, this widget has a margin too large.
How to change the size of the margin

I expect the margin to be smaller and can close with the widget
My code for the widget:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_layout"
    android:minWidth="304dp"
    android:minHeight="150dp"
    android:description="@string/brave_quick_action_search"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen" />

And this is file quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_layout.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutSearchWithBrave"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_search_bg"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/app_icon"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:importantForAccessibility="no"/>
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSearchWithBrave"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text="@string/search_with_brave"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_text_color"
                    tools:ignore="UseCompatTextViewDrawableXml" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivVoiceSearch"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_search_bg"
                android:contentDescription="@string/accessibility_toolbar_btn_mic"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_mic"
                android:tint="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                tools:ignore="UseAppTint" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivIncognito"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_search_bg"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button_new_incognito_tab"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/brave_menu_new_private_tab"
                android:tint="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                tools:ignore="UseAppTint" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/BookmarkLayoutRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow1Bookmark1"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow1Bookmark1Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow1Bookmark1Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow1Bookmark2"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow1Bookmark2Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow1Bookmark2Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow1Bookmark3"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow1Bookmark3Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow1Bookmark3Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow1Bookmark4"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow1Bookmark4Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow1Bookmark4Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/BookmarkLayoutRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow2Bookmark1"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow2Bookmark1Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow2Bookmark1Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow2Bookmark2"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow2Bookmark2Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow2Bookmark2Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow2Bookmark3"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow2Bookmark3Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow2Bookmark3Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow2Bookmark4"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow2Bookmark4Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow2Bookmark4Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/BookmarkLayoutRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow3Bookmark1"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow3Bookmark1Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow3Bookmark1Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow3Bookmark2"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow3Bookmark2Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow3Bookmark2Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow3Bookmark3"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow3Bookmark3Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow3Bookmark3Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow3Bookmark4"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow3Bookmark4Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow3Bookmark4Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/BookmarkLayoutRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow4Bookmark1"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow4Bookmark1Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow4Bookmark1Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow4Bookmark2"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow4Bookmark2Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow4Bookmark2Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow4Bookmark3"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow4Bookmark3Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow4Bookmark3Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutRow4Bookmark4"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivRow4Bookmark4Icon"
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_bookmark_bg"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_visited_site" />
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRow4Bookmark4Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_tint"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



Thanks so much

please share the xml file for "@layout/quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_layout"

I updated quick_action_search_and_bookmark_widget_layout.xml file. Thank you

Try removing the padding from the first linear layout, or changing the third linear layouts height to less or to wrap content.
